# SharePoint REST Integration with OAuth

Tags: sharepoint, oauth, microsoft-graph-api

I have to integrate SharePoint with my web app(just want to show the content of the user account).

For that, I have researched and I am looking for the SharePoint integration with REST API through OAuth process, Right now I found a different way where users have to create their SharePoint app and they have to share username and password and then I can get the data with their credential for the users.

The above approach is not a good option.

Please help if someone knows how to get share point content through the OAuth approach with REST.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to connect to Microsoft Graph which hosts an API for the Office365 entities such as Calendar, Mail, Sharepoint etc.

In order to authenticate, you need to follow the OAuth 2.0 flow. This involves the generation of access tokens, which are then used in case of username/password.

More information about the MS Graph API and setting up authentication as well as a number of SDKs can be found: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-register-app-v2?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: Would you please share the graph API document link for SharePoint because as I researched i did not get the graph API support for SharePoint

Comment: @VishalSolanki do you mean this documentation for [SharePoint REST API v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/sharepoint-rest-graph) or the general [Working with SharePoint sites in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0)  information?

Comment: I am looking for the Microsoft Graph APIs Information

Comment: Sorry for delay, Build was a busy time. Here are docs on [OneDrive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onedrive?view=graph-rest-1.0#commonly-accessed-resources) (Files) API as well as [SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0#sharepoint-api-root-resources) (Sites) API.  Let me know if this isn't what you were looking for.